# In what use case would Mutational and Feedback fuzzing be used in?

Tags: network, penetration-test, scan, fuzzing

I am currently working on an assignment paper that asks how each type of fuzzing would work and in what use case they would be used.

I defined Feedback as a tool that would throw inputs which would deviate and check to see if those deviated inputs would open up paths. If those paths were open, they would "continue" down this path for what I would believe to be "information gathering". As for its use case, I could not think of much other than identifying potential failovers, but I was unsure if this would qualify as an answer.

Mutational Fuzzing I just defined as it working on modifying valid inputs randomly to create random testing data. For this, I assumed that with the random data being sent to the target, it would be useful for SQL injections. However, I was again unsure if this would qualify as an answer due to being vague.

I would appreciate anyone to please guide me to the right direction, as I have been searching and getting more confused at the information I have been finding.